# How to load a JDBC driver dynamically during runtime since Java 9?

Tags: java, jdbc, classloader

I'm currently migrating my Java 8 code to Java 11 and stumbled across a problem. I'm looking for jar files in a directory and add them to the classpath in order to use them as JDBC drivers.

After doing so I can easily use `DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcString);` to get a connection to any database I loaded a driver beforehand.

I used to load drivers using this bit of code which no longer works since the SystemClassLoader is no longer a URLClassLoader.

```
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[] { jdbcDriver.toURI().toURL() });
```

So after looking around for alternatives I found this answer on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14479658/10511969

Unfortunately for this approach I'd need the drivers class name, i.e. "org.postgresql.Driver" which I don't know.

Is there just no way to do this anymore, or am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure if that works in Java 11: You could create a new `URLClassLoader` then use `ServiceLoader.load()` (passing that URL class loader) to find services implementing `java.sql.Driver`

Answer (score 1):

Using a Shim is a good way to load the JDBC driver when the driver is, for some reason, not accessibile via the system class loader context.   I have ran into this a few times with multi-threaded scripts that have their own separated classpath context.

http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/Java/dyn-jdbc.html

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the driver's class seems like an odd constraint.

I would go for a custom class loader that after ever class initialisation (I think you can do that), calls `DriverManager.getDrivers` and registers any new drivers it finds. (I have no time at the moment to write the code.)

The hacky alternative would be to load all your code (except a bootstrap) in a `URLClassLoader` and `addURL` to that.

**Edit:** So I wrote some code.

It creates a class loader for the drivers that also contains a "scout" class that forwards `DriverManager.drivers` (which is a naughty caller sensitive method (a newish one!)). A fake driver within the application class loader forwards connect attempts onto any dynamically loaded drivers at the time of request.

I don't have any JDBC 4.0 or later drivers conveniently around to test this on. You'll probably want to change the URL - you'll need the `Scout` class and the driver jar.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class FakeJDBCDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
            new URL[] { new java.io.File("dynamic").toURI().toURL() },
            FakeJDBCDriver.class.getClassLoader()
        );
        Class<?> scout = loader.loadClass("Scout");
        Method driversMethod = scout.getMethod("drivers");
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver() {
            public int getMajorVersion() {
                return 0;
            }
            public int getMinorVersion() {
                return 0;
            }
            public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
                throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
            }
            public DriverPropertyInfo[] getPropertyInfo(String url, Properties info) {
                return new DriverPropertyInfo[] { };
            }
            public boolean jdbcCompliant() {
                return false;
            }
            public boolean acceptsURL(String url) throws SQLException {
                if (url == null) {
                    throw new SQLException();
                }
                for (Iterator<Driver> iter=drivers(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                    Driver driver = iter.next();
                    if (
                        driver.getClass().getClassLoader() == loader &&
                        driver.acceptsURL(url)
                    ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {
                if (url == null) {
                    throw new SQLException();
                }
                for (Iterator<Driver> iter=drivers(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                    Driver driver = iter.next();
                    if (
                        driver.getClass().getClassLoader() == loader &&
                        driver.acceptsURL(url)
                    ) {
                        Connection connection = driver.connect(url, info);
                        if (connection != null) {
                            return connection;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            private Iterator<Driver> drivers() {
                try {
                    return ((Stream<Driver>)driversMethod.invoke(null)).iterator();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException exc) {
                    throw new Error(exc);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException exc) {
                    Throwable cause = exc.getTargetException();
                    if (cause instanceof Error) {
                        throw (Error)cause;
                    } else if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
                        throw (RuntimeException)cause;
                    } else {
                        throw new Error(exc);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // This the driver I'm trying to access, but isn't even in a jar.
        Class.forName("MyDriver", true, loader);

        // Just some nonsense to smoke test.
        System.err.println(DriverManager.drivers().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        System.err.println(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mydriver"));
    }
}
```

Within a directory `dynamic` (relative to current working directory):

```
import java.sql.*;

public interface Scout {
    public static java.util.stream.Stream<Driver> drivers() {
        return DriverManager.drivers();
    }
}
```

I would always suggest avoiding setting the thread context class loader to anything other than a loader that denies everything, or perhaps `null`.

Modules may well allow you to load drivers cleanly, but I've not looked.

Comment: I want the user to be able to just throw the jdbc driver jar for whatever database hes using into a directory, enter a connection string and be good to go. But maybe it's sufficient to roll out with the 5 most databases used currently and be done with it.

Comment: @M.Folte I forgetting the many and varied ways JDBC drivers get discovered. It was all `Class.forName` in my day. There's a manifest entry now, isn't there? (I'm sure I wrote a blog entry about dynamically loading JDBC drivers before jroller went south.)

Answer (score 0):

if you don`t know the driver name, you cannot use reflect to use urlLoader to load jar, which you exactly want.
I have same problem with dynamically load driver, because of jars are conflict.
Even though, I have to know the driver name to jar, which i want to load use my url class loader.

DriverManager use class loader to load jar, so it could find jdbc driver by name. As usual we use: class.forName。
We use self defined class loader to load our driver, so that it can solve the conflict of jars.