# The program works in IDE but not on the export jar

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I have to connect my database with java. The program work fine in my Eclipse IDE but when i export in jar file . I get this error:
connection failure: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://myServer:1433;databaseName=mydb

This is my code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DriverManagerSql {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://myServer:1433;databaseName=mydb";
        String username = "sa";
        String password = "12345";
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
            if (connection != null) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "good connection");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "connection failure:" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("Error while closing the connection: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I want the same result as the ide

Comment: How are you packaging or running the jar? Seems like it’s missing either a classpath or it’s packaged incorrectly.

Comment: right click on the project -> export -> Runnable JAR file -> Extract required libraries into generated JAR

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work. You are exporting a JAR of only your code. You need the dependencies on the classpath too, either in the same jar or in separate ones.

Comment: Jorn, can you tell me how to do it in eclipse please. I exported the file using -> Package required libraries into generated JAR, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by reinstalling JDK on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the required driver is not located in the classpath.

If your application requires dependencies, you should strongly consider using build and dependency management tool such as [Maven or Gradle](https://www.baeldung.com/ant-maven-gradle).

Since you appear to be trying to build a single runnable jar, you'll probably want to use the [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow) (depending on your build tool) to package your dependencies, such as the database driver, into your executable jar.

If an Uber-jar containing your dependencies is not what you're after and you would prefer to load the db driver from another jar on disk, you can can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478870/dynamically-load-the-jdbc-driver/14479658#14479658) in order to load the driver into your classpath.

Comment: In another pc my jar function perfectly only in mine not function